# Highcharts: Change Pie Colors By Clicking on a button

Tags: charts, click, highcharts, pie-chart

I would like to know if anyone can figure out how I can change this line chart to a pie chart and still make the button change the color of the pie color like it did the line color?

http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/637ns/

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
        }]
    });

    // the button handler
    $('#button').click(function() {
        chart.series[0].color = "#FF0000";
        chart.series[0].graph.attr({ stroke: '#FF0000' });

        $.each(chart.series[0].data, function(i, point) {
           point.graphic.attr({ fill: '#FF0000' });            
         });
        chart.redraw();
    });
});
```

I would like to add a click event to change the color of the pie chart.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use attribute fill to change slice color: http://jsfiddle.net/637ns/8/

```
 chart.series[0].data[4].graphic.attr({ fill: '#FF0000' });
```